# Manipulate Json String Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string

Supposed that I have this JSON STRING that is stored in a vairable:

```
{"name":"Joene Floresca"},{"name":"Argel "}
```

How can I make it

```
["Joene", "Argel"]
```

Comment: Your JSON would be invalid without a `[]` around it to make it an array.

Comment: `[{"name":"Joene Floresca"},{"name":"Argel "}]` this is the correct way right?- @RGraham

Comment: you can use jQuery.parseJSON(); refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ for further info.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca `var jsonstring = '[{"name":"Joene Floresca"},{"name":"Argel "}]';` is json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you have a **string**. Use `JSON.parse` for that. Also, make sure it is an array. Afterwards, you can manually iterate through each object in the array and push the value

```js
var str = '[{"name": "Joene Floresca"},{ "name": "Argel "}]';
var objA = JSON.parse(str);
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < objA.length; i++) {
  for (var key in objA[i]) {
    values.push(objA[i][key]);
  }
}

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON is an array, you can use [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```js
// Your JSON string variable
var jsonString = '[{"name":"Joene Floresca"},{"name":"Argel "}]';
// Parse the JSON to a JS Object
var jsObject = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
// Use map to iterate the array
var arr = $.map(jsObject, function(element) {
    // Return the name element from each object
    return element.name;
});
console.log(arr); // Prints ["Joene Floresca", "Argel "]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `objects` inside array and store the names in a second array.

```js
var data =  JSON.parse('[{"name":"Joene Floresca"},{"name":"Argel "}]');
var names = [];

data.forEach(function(model) {
  names.push(model.name);
});
// names now contains ["Joene Floresca", "Argel"]
alert(names);
```